# Migrar dados de uma versão para outra - Sqlite Android

Tags: android, sqlite

No aplicativo que eu estou trabalhando, eu tenho que salvar os dados de uma tabela específica quando o aplicativo for atualizado. Essa ação precisa acontecer antes da tabela ser descartada no método onUpgrade. Eu preciso fazer isso porque quando o aplicativo é atualizado eu quero que o usuário continue logado no sistema após a atualização. Os dados do usuário são os únicos dados que eu quero reutilizar. meu método onUpgrade está assim:

```
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, ConnectionSource connectionSource, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
try {

    TableUtils.dropTable(connectionSource, User.class, true);
    ... other tables


    // after we drop the old databases, we create the new ones
    onCreate(db, connectionSource);

} catch (SQLException e) {
    Log.e(DatabaseHelper.class.getName(), "Can't drop databases", e);
    throw new RuntimeException(e);
}
}
```

Como posso implementar essa persistência?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Não sei que tipo de upgrade você quer fazer ao banco de dados mas esse upgrade pode ser feito com ou sem a necessidade de eliminar e depois recriar todas as tabelas.
Para isso, no método `onUpdate()`, utilize comandos SQL do tipo ALTER TABLE e CREATE TABLE para fazer as alterações.

Caso isso não seja viável/prático ou queira apenas manter alguns dados, leia esses dados para a memória, faça o *drop* das tabelas, chame o método `onCreate()` e reponha os dados guardados.

Comment: Ok, @ramaral vou tentar implementar nessa opção de trazer para a memória.

Comment: Resolvido! Vi aqui com o gerente do projeto e não havia a necessidade efetiva de deletar a tabela de usuário.
Carrego o usuário na memória, não deleto mais a tabela no onUpgrade e quando chamo novamente o onCreate não crio novamente caso a tabela de usuário já estaja criada.

Answer (score 1):

Uma opção seria você não salvar os dados do usuário em banco mas sim nas [sharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings.html), que não trabalham com upgrade.